# Is there a way to output HTML within Firebug's console?

Tags: html, firebug, xdebug, console.log, var-dump

I'm using Firebug's `console.log()` to output Xdebug's `var_dump()` result and it looks like this:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'offset' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'40'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
</pre>
```

Is there some way to output it as processed HTML without using the HTML tab within the *Net* panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug doesn't allow to output arbitrary HTML within the *Console* panel due to security reasons and to avoid breaking the display of the output. So you are not able to let the *Console* panel display your XDebug output.

The *Console* panel provides [limited formatting options](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/923845aa917ead8bcd0390e98a14a694ccdce9ba/extension/content/firebug/console/consolePanel.js#L41), though. The allowed CSS properties include all `background-*`, `border-*`, `color`, `font-*`, `*line*`, `margin-*`, `padding-*` and `text-*` properties.

To get PHP debug output you may install the Firebug extension [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/). It works together with a server component, which lets you log information from within your PHP environment via an [`fb()` function](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm).